# Visualizing superclass types in GraphDB's visual graph

Tags: sparql, graphdb

I have the following graph:

```
:Bar rdf:type owl:Class .

:Foo rdf:type owl:Class ;
     rdfs:subClassOf :Bar .

:my_foo a :Foo .
```

When I check the info panel for `:my_foo` in GraphDB's visual graph, it displays just the badge for the class `:Foo` and not for the superclass `:Bar`. Is there a way to have the complete list of types in such a panel?

Comment: Perhaps is it a typo but ou speak about :bar and :Bar

Comment: And also, `SELECT * WHERE { ?x rdfs:subClassOf+ ?y }` is transitive and take at least one subClassOf

Comment: Is the question answered?

Comment: No, or at least, I’m not sure of having recognized an answer in your comments. The graph I described is just a semplification to summarize the general problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sesame:directType` predicate is used, when content for this info panel is retrieved.

> Resource I is a direct type of T if:
>
> 1. I is of type T and
> 2. There is no class U (not equal to T) such that:
>      a. U is a subclass of T, and
>      b. I is of type U.

[Source](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/query-behaviour.html#how-to-use-rdf4j-direct-hierarchy-vocabulary)

In the `describeResource.sparql` file within the `graphdb-framework-graph-explore-8.2.0.jar` archive, replace `sesame:directType` with `rdf:type`.

[image: Info panel]

Comment: Great! Instead of hard coding the modification in the source code, can we do the same in the advanced graph configurations section?

Comment: Well, obviously you can write something like `SELECT ?property ?value { ?node ?property ?value . VALUES (?property){(rdf:type)} }` in the "Node extra" configuration section. However, this will affect only list of properties and only when this visualization configuration is selected...

Comment: Or simply: `SELECT ?type { ?node rdf:type ?type.} ORDER BY ?type`. As you observed, it will affect just that configuration.

Comment: "The variable `?property` must be selected."

Comment: Put that query in 'Node basics'